# Permission to People but not Account Settings

Tags: users

I am looking to give a user the permission to manage users (add/edit/remove) on the page /admin/people. But I do not want them to be able to access the Account Settings page on /admin/config/people/accounts. (As you can change the Administrator Role).

How would this be possible?

Note I have already installed the Role Delation module, so they can only assign new users a certain role.

Comment: You could look into custom route access checks and define the exact logic for this particular route `/admin/config/people/accounts` - `return AccessResult::forbidden()` if a user is not admin. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

Comment: Would be good to know what version of Drupal you're asking for

Comment: If you're on Drupal 8, these permissions are separate. `Administer account settings` allows access to "Configuration > People" where you can change the admin role etc.  `Administer users` allows access to "People > List"